# render the page block section Section 1 & Section 2 on the basis of record type selected through the picklist field .please help

Tags: visualforce

VF Page:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Financial_Records__c" extensions="FinancialRecordController1" sidebar="false" >
      <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Information">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="RecordTypeInformation">
             <apex:inputField value="{!fr.Record_Type__c}"  />
              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateData}" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>


            <apex:pageBlockSection title="LossInformation" id="section1" rendered="{!section1}" >
            <br><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Financial_Records__c.Standard_Solutions__c}"/></br>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Reason__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Approver__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Responsibility__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Cost_Adjustment_Amount__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Sub_Responsibility__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Cost_Adjustment_Currency__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Comments__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Amount_in_POS__c}"/>
                <br><apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Amount_in_POS_Currency__c}"/></br>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>



              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recovered Loss Information" Columns="2" id="section2" rendered="{!section2}" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Approver__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Recovered_Loss_Amount__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Recovered_Loss_Currency__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Comments__c}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>



            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
               <apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!save}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class FinancialRecordController1 {
          public Financial_Records__c fr {get; set;}
          public Boolean section1 {get; set;}
          public Boolean section2 {get; set;}

    public FinancialRecordController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

     public FinancialRecordController1() {
            section1 = false;
            section2 = false;

          }

          public void updateData() {
             if(fr.Record_Type__c == 'Loss') {
                  section1 = true;
                  section2 = false;
             } else if(fr.Record_Type__c == 'Recovered Loss') {
                  section1 = false;
                  section2 = true;
             }
          }
}
```

Comment: what kind of field Record_Type__c is ? Is it lookup to some custom object or a text field ?

Answer (score 1):

considering Record_Type__c to be a text field below code will work:

```
<apex:page standardController="Financial_Records__c" extensions="FinancialRecordController1" sidebar="false" >
      <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Information">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="RecordTypeInformation">
             <apex:inputField value="{!fr.Record_Type__c}"  >
              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="dependentSections" />
             </apex:inputField>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>

           <apex:outputpanel id="dependentSections">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="LossInformation" id="section1" rendered="{!fr.Record_Type__c=='Loss'}" >
            <br><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Financial_Records__c.Standard_Solutions__c}"/></br>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Reason__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Approver__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Responsibility__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Cost_Adjustment_Amount__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Sub_Responsibility__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Cost_Adjustment_Currency__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Comments__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Amount_in_POS__c}"/>
                <br><apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Amount_in_POS_Currency__c}"/></br>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>



              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recovered Loss Information" Columns="2" id="section2" rendered="{!fr.Record_Type__c=='Recovered Loss'}" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Loss_Approver__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Recovered_Loss_Amount__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Recovered_Loss_Currency__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!Financial_Records__c.Comments__c}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputpanel>


            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
               <apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!save}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

You don't need any apex code at controller side. Also in Case your Record_Type__c field is lookup to some custom object you have to change rendered conditions appropriately. For example `{!fr.Record_type__c.Name=='Loss'}`